# Messing with buttons and TextFields with reusable cells in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I would like to create a message board with custom table view cells. Every cell has a button for liking a message. As in the Facebook app, I want to inform the user that he pressed the button with changing its image (in the background it sends a code to a server to save liking). If the user press again on the changed button, than he will unlike the message.

My problem is, if i press on button of a cell, the image will change, but after scrolling i can see other cells with the same unpressed button but with changed image. If i scroll up and down, the image changes always randomly in the cells. This is the problem with textfields, if i type in a cell, my text is show up in an other cell. What is the solution for this problem?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
MessagesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
    cell = [[MessagesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
//...
    [cell.likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendLike:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//...
}

- (void)sendLike:(id)sender {
UIButton * button = sender;
MessagesCell *cell = (MessagesCell *)button.superview.superview.superview;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.messagesTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

if([cell.likeButton.imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notliked"]])
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notliked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not seperating your data (Model) from the cells (View). You shouldn't use the UITableViewCells to store your data. Cells are reused, which basically means when one scrolls off screen it will be reused again for another row. The state of it's child-controls are maintained.

You could store whether an item is liked in an array, for instance. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath determine which image should be displayed based on the items in that array, not based on a child-control of the cell. Always persist data to some non-ui structure.

This will result in a better MVC separation.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution. Every cell checks on the server that the message liked or not, and the answer will be stored in a mutable array. If the user press the button, the cell will be reloaded with the changed mutable array.
And can I do anything with textfields? I don't want to store datas there, i would use them for writing comments and after sending clear them. But during writing if I scroll down, there will be my typed text in another textfield. Could You give me advice for this case? Thank You for helping!

Comment: same goes for the textfields. When a cell is displayed, you need to provide it with all the data you want it to show. After entering text in a textfield, store it somewhere; locally or on the server. You simply should not use a cell for storing data; it should be stateless. Get it out of the View!

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Cell is set to reusable, so identifier for each cell should be different. Otherwise it will consider every cell same and mess things.

Set your identifier like below

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];

        MessagesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MessagesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

I hope your problem will be resolved now.

Comment: cell reuse is there for a reason. This solution goes around a good MVC design. not recommended.